# Expectation of inverse of variable which is lognormal

Tags: probability

If $\log(X)\sim N(a,b^2)$ for a random variable $X$, what is the expectation of $\frac{1}{X}$?

Comment: $E[X^s] = e^{s a + \frac{1}{2} s^2 b^2 }$. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments).

Comment: Wow... I appreciate moments significantly more now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\log(X) \sim N(a,b^2)$ then $\log(1/X)=-\log(X)\sim N(-a,b^2)$, so the question is: if $\log Y\sim N(-a,b^2)$ then what is $\operatorname E(Y)$?  (Can you take it from there?)

Comment: Nice use of symmetry!